# Выполнить данную проще, упростить, улучшить

Tags: php, php8

Есть массив, который собираю в цикле, предположим собрали

```
$insert =  ["('текст')", "('текст1')"];
```

Далее, для того чтобы записать в бд и не создавать дубликат. Выполняю следующий запрос

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `tag` (`title`) VALUES ".implode(',', $insert)
```

Ок, далее необходимо получить все id что записали и тех, что уже есть в бд. Для этого, опять же в том же цикле что собрали первый массив, собираем еще один, на выходе получаем

```
$select =  ["текст", "текст1"];
```

Далее выполняю запрос и в цикле перебраю

```
select id from `tag` where title in('".implode("','", $select)."')
while($r = $db->get_row())
   $id[] = $r['id'];
```

В результате, записал недостающие теги и получил массив `id` всех тегов которые прописал пользователь.

Вопрос в том, возможно ли данную процедуру делать иначе. Проще, меньше кода, вместо одного массива к примеру. Оперировать одним?

Comment: `все id что записали и тех, что уже есть в бд` - то есть, надо просто все id получить.. зачем второй массив?

Comment: Второй массив, содержит исключительно имена, который через `implode` вставляем в запрос, а в цикле собираем результат. Второй массив содержит тоже имена но уже к примеру `('текст1')` чтобы в `INSERT IGNORE INTO` также через `implode`  вставить запрос и записать недостающие.

Comment: вообще-то, после записи в БД там будут все недублирующиеся значения. После второй операции у вас в массиве  получится, что какие-то элементы по нескольку раз. Это вам важно?

Comment: `$select = array_map(fn($str) => preg_replace("/[\'\(\)]+/", "", $str), $insert);`

Comment: Для меня важно, чтобы в таблице не было одинаковых имен в одном из полей. При выполнении `INSERT IGNORE INTO` возможно сразу получить все id не только тех строчек которые записали, а так же тех которые проигнорировали на запись?